# Image Processing in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

What is the right start in image processing using C#
I need to know the tools and algorithms to start understanding
Thanks

Comment: you need to be a bit more specific rather than just "image processing" - are u trying to create images, resize images or just show them to the client - we need more information before we can help you I'm afraid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a great series on Code Project by Christian Graus which you might find useful:

> [Image Processing for Dummies with C# and GDI+ Part 1 - Per Pixel Filters](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/csharpgraphicfilters11.aspx)
>   [Image Processing for Dummies with C# and GDI+ Part 2 - Convolution Filters](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/csharpfilters.aspx)
>   [Image Processing for Dummies with C# and GDI+ Part 3 - Edge Detection Filters](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/edge_detection.aspx)
>   [Image Processing for Dummies with C# and GDI+ Part 4 - Bilinear Filters and Resizing](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imageprocessing4.aspx)
>   [Image Processing for Dummies with C# and GDI+ Part 5 - Displacement filters, including swirl](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/displacementfilters.aspx)
>   [Image Processing for Dummies with C# and GDI+ Part 6 - The HSL color space](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/HSLColorSpace.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tmorley.net/ has downloadable PDF guides that explain the basics of image processing algorithms and takes you step-by-step through writing C# programs to process images.  You can also download the code and executables.

Comment: Could point to the right page with your link instead of the homepage ?

Answer (score -1):

System.Drawing Namespace is what you are looking for.